# Как настроить таблицы?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Я создал две таблицы Customers и Orders.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers] (
    [Id]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Adress] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) );



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (
    [Id]          INT           NOT NULL,
    [Number]      INT           NULL,
    [Date]        DATETIME      NULL,
    [Amount]      INT           NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [CustomerId]  INT           NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Customers] FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([Id])
);
```

Функционал такой: при создании покупателя присваиваю ему заказ. 
При выведении мастер страницы выводятся данные: покупатель и соответствующий ему заказ. И вот вопрос. **Как настроить таблицу что бы можно было редактировать и удалять как покупателя, оставив только заказ и наоборот, удалить заказ, оставив покупателя.**
Спасибо !

Comment: Убрать FOREIGN KEY

Comment: А какой физический смысл заказа без покупателя? Черная бухгалтерия какая-то :)

Comment: Хорошо Денис, вы меня убедили. Тогда сделаем зависимость заказа от покупателя. Это связь один ко многим ? Как тогда организовать таблицы? Так и оставить ?